# Slight gapping between navbar border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Sort of a weird issue that I can't seem to find an answer to online, so I'll see if anyone else here has experienced a similar problem.

I have a relatively tall bootstrap 3 navbar (110px in height) with a gradient background.

I want to add a 1px border to the bottom of the navbar just so it blends into my page a bit better, but for some reason when I do this there is a slight gap (appears to be about 1px) where I can see through the navbar to what's behind the page.

I tried to replicate the issue on codepen but for whatever reason, the issue isn't happening when I do it there so I included a screenshot below.

[navbar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkXLy.jpg)

Not sure if you can make it out or not but there is a gap between the bottom of the navbar and the 1px border. I made the border in orange just so it's easier to see.

```css
body {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height:100%;
  }

 .navbar-default {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 
  100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  height:110px;
  padding:30px 0;
    }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- 
     toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
       controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
   </nav>
```

If anyone has any helpful tips on how to perhaps remove this gapping it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add where you are getting this error.In your snippet only navigation without any error.

Comment: In your code `</nav>` is not close.

Comment: I think navbar.less has following css .navbar-fixed-top { border-width: 0 0 1px; } It is this 1px border.

Comment: My code has the closing </nav> tag it just didn't paste properly, I edited it in. 
I tried changing the border-width property of the bottom border to medium and it seems to fix the gapping, although the border is a little thicker than I would like it to be. If anyone has any other suggestions I'm open to trying them, otherwise I might have to make it work like this.